# Is there a way to write an if in statement using an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to right a function that can recognize integers in a string. I'm new to python so I'm sorry if its a simple question. Previously I have used statements like

```
if he in hello:
```

I'm wondering if there's something similar to this but instead of it being "he" or whatever it could be a number. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do this: `str(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be that you convert the number to a string?

```py
num = 5;
numString = "This string has 5 in it"

if str(num) in numString:
    print("Yay")
else:
    print("Nah")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the integer to a string:

```py
my_int = 123
my_str = "98483123994"

if str(my_int) in my_str:
    print("YES!")
else:
    print("NO!")
```

Does that work for your case?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and yes it did thank you!